# New Haarcascade for Opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, face-detection, object-detection

i'm searching for **NEW*** Haarcascade for OpenCV. It can be anything - face, human, car, whatever, right now i just need it for some test. Unfortunately all cascades included to OpenCV and everything i've founded on the internet (mostly here - http://alereimondo.no-ip.org/OpenCV/34/ ) are not new. To be honest - i don't know what's the difference between old and new format. I need it in new format because it's much easier to modify code which detects objects using new cascade format.
Of course the best thing for me would be converter but just one haarcascade in new format will be great as well.

*new cascade - cascade in new format, which means that after loading:

```
CascadeClassifier haar = CascadeClassifier("some_haar_cascade.xml");
```

calling `haar.isOldFormatCascade()` will return false.

Answer (score 1):

[those should be all in the new format](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/data)

(you can only use the softcascade with the master version)

Comment: Those cascades are all in old format - look at the modify date here https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades - 4 years ago...

Comment: oh, sorry, - you are right, all the haarcascades are in the old formats, only the lbp and hog cascades are in the new format.